# how to select one dom which has not one specify property?

Tags: dom, jquery-selectors, selectors-api

suppose i have some html dom elements like

```
<slot></slot>
<slot name='slotWithName'></slot>
```

how to find the first slot dom through querySelector() method?

i have tried `document.querySelector("slot :not([name])")`

just not work :(

Answer (score 0):

ok, i find the anwser by myself

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('slot'))
.filter(function(el){ return !el.name })
```

Comment: its not an answer for `through querySelector() method`

Comment: it is ok for myself, no matter querySelector or querySelectorAll

what i want is find a specify dom

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
querySelector('slot:not([name])')
```